# Why does Catch(object o) cause a compile error?

Tags: java, exception

```
try {

} catch(Object o) {

}
```

why this is leads to a compile error ? since all the objects inherit from Object class.

Comment: Because you can only catch `Throwable`

Comment: No exception of type Object can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of `Throwable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only catch objects that derive from `Throwable`.

See [Throwable (Java Platform)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html), which states:

> The Throwable class is the superclass of all errors and exceptions in
>   the Java language. Only objects that are instances of this class (or
>   one of its subclasses) are thrown by the Java Virtual Machine or can
>   be thrown by the Java throw statement. Similarly, only this class or
>   one of its subclasses can be the argument type in a catch clause.